# USB devices disappeared raspberry pi 4 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, power-management, raspberrypi

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic on a raspberry pi 4 model B.

Everything was working fine since last week, when I did some apt upgrades. lsusb and lspci show nothing at all.

I'm adding dmesg output:

```
dmesg | grep usb
[    0.085818] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.085873] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.085981] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.595714] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    2.598290] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    4.503348] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[   13.067589] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
```

In the beggining I thought it was a hardware problem so I checked with the multimeter and the pins powering the USBs had 0V. But I realized that was not the problem after I installed a new SD card with ubuntu 20 and the USB ports were working properly.

After that, I tried to deactivate the autosuspend by trying several things (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above). In the end I didn't succeed.

I also downgraded the kernel just to try another possibility but it seems not to work either.

**The most strage thing is that the keyboard is not working at all even during the system boot. Although using the ubuntu 20 works perfectly fine.**

I hope some of this makes sense to somebody.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am very happy that you found the solution to your problem and written the answer and accepted your answer as correct with the green check mark. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback user68186.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the kernel to the latest version solved the problem.

I used the following commands:

List available kernels

**apt list linux-image*raspi**

Select a kernel and install

**sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-image-5.4.0-1047-raspi**

**sudo apt update**

**sudo apt upgrade**

Then rebooted the system and the USBs are working again.